# resttemplate postForObject with json data in request throwing RestClientException with 404 null

Tags: java, post

I have the following working cURL -

```
curl -X POST \
  http://someurl.com/verify \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{

"param1":"5661014333489020317", 

"source":"WALLET"

}'
```

Which returns the following response with a 200 OK -

```
{
    "validated": true,
    "refKey": "ab186997-1c41",
 }
```

I have the following code -

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = RestTemplateClient.getRestTemplate(10, 10);
String refKey = "";
String finalApiUrl = apiBaseUrl + "/verify";

JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("param1", uuidOfRecipient);
json.put("source", "WALLET");

try {

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(json.toString(),
            headers);

    String response = restTemplate.postForObject(finalApiUrl, entity,
            String.class);
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
    String val = jsonObj.get("validated").toString();
    if (val.equals("true")) {
        refKey = jsonObj.get("refKey").toString();
    }
} catch (RestClientException ex) {
    logger.error("Ex {}", ex.getMessage());

}
```

I am getting the following exception right after the postForObject() call -

```
Ex 404 null
```

Comment: Can u check your URL again?

Comment: Oh, it was a case of capital case, like /verify was /Verify

Comment: That's it. Solved